# Seeking a "softphone" app for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, voip

I'm moving towards IP-telephony and need a SIP-client for my mobile phone.

My first choice would've been Linphone, because that's what I use on my desktop, but it disconnects from the provider every time the phone goes into "standby"... I can make calls using it whenever I want, but, if somebody calls me on the VoIP-number, when my phone's screen is dark, they just get a message stating: "The subscriber is not available".

According to my VoIP-provider, this is a known problem -- I wonder, if there is a SIP-client, that solved it... Obviously, Skype and WhatsApp don't suffer from it...

If it matters, the VoIP provider only accepts UDP (sensible) traffic, and ZRTP is the sole means of encryption.

The family's iPhones are 5c, 5s, and 7 -- with the latest iOS at the moment.

Comment: Zoiper an option?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Acrobits Softphone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/acrobits-softphone-sip-phone-for-voip-calls/id314192799?mt=8), and it is working very fine for me.

It supports many VoIP providers - here is a list: https://www.acrobits.net/about-us/partners#tab_verified-voip-operators.

ZRTP is supported too: https://doc.acrobits.net/general/secure_communication.html

Comment: Thanks. Callcentric also mentioned Acrobits, but it costs $7, so, spoiled as I am, I was looking for a free alternative :-)

Comment: Does Acrobits maintain connection to the VoIP-server, when the phone goes idle, turns off its screen and locks up? Both M5 and GS Wave lose the connection (I guess, the OS fully suspends them)...

Comment: As long the phone is open (you haven't closed down the app - so both foreground and background), then it works as a normal phone, where you receives calls. And if you want to close the app down, you can register your phone number to a remote server, and you'll get a push call instead. Here are some reading: https://www.acrobits.net/hesk/knowledgebase.php?article=52 and https://www.acrobits.net/hesk/knowledgebase.php?article=60

Comment: No, I'm fine with leaving the app running -- but all the other clients I tried lose connection, when the phone self-closes... As far as "register your phone number to a remote server" -- whose server? Acrobits' or my VoIP provider's? The latter do not support such a thing :(

Comment: It is a Acrobits server located in USA - it is also described in the links.

Comment: Does that mean, Acrobits will be my VoIP provider? Or will they register themselves with my existing provider to get notified of every call -- and notify my phone?

Comment: As I understand (I haven't activated the Push Notification), your ISPs account data will be sent to the Push server when activated - see here how this is done: https://www.acrobits.net/hesk/knowledgebase.php?article=2  and the server will then notify you when someone call you - this also means that your ISP need to accept this set up (account date is sent to remote server).

Answer (score 0):

M5/ mediaphone is really good, and there's no one-way audio issues as with many iPhone softphones.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.